# Jest how to mock and test dynamodb documentClient errors

Tags: jestjs, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

this is the code I have to query the data from database. The query will return list of response promises, and I am resolving the promises using Promise.all().

```
    const resultPromises = ids.map((id) => 
           await documentClient
                        .query({
                          TableName: 'table-name',
                          IndexName: 'by-index-all',
                          ProjectionExpression:'....',
                          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                            ':id':id,
                          },
                          KeyConditionExpression:
                            'id = :id',
                        })
                        .promise()
                        .catch((e) => {
                          dbErrors.push(e);
                        });
    
const queryResponses = await Promise.all(queryPromises);
```

The code to throw the error

```
throw new Error(JSON.stringify(dbErrors));
```

The resolved promise is undefined if there is any error when fetching from database. My question is how can I mock the test for this case? I can only mock undefined response returned but cannot trigger the error. How should I mock the error triggering process? ( Catch the error and assign it to errors array and throw it )

```
  documentClient.query.mockReturnValueOnce({promise: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(undefined)});
```